# quotation generator with loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on this quotation generator with loop. The generator has to return a random quote from array 1 + array 2 + array 3 ( like 'love' 'will be' 'your tasks' )but when it gets "peace" "will be" "your start" it has to alert: "you found me".
the problem i believe is function select.quote that is not working

```
let array1 = [ " peace " , "love" , " money"];
let array2 = [ " will be " , "will never be ", "maybe will be"];
let array3 = [" your end", " your start", "your tasks"];

function finalQuote(...arrs) {
let quote = '';
for (let i = 0; i <arrs.length; i++) {
quote += arrs[i][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];{
return quote;}

select.quote = function(){
if (arrays){
if (array1 === 'peace', array2 === 'will be', array3 === 'your end'){
alert("you found me!");
}}else{
let FinalQuote =finalQuote(array1, array2, array3);}}

qt_btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
finalQuote();});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have not mentioned what the actual issue is and what is currently happening (vs what you think should happen). Please elaborate so that anyone can help!

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. It should return randomly strings from array 1, array 2, array 3 ( like 'love' 'will be' 'your tasks' ) but when the generator generate '"peace" "will be" "your start" it has to alert "you found me". the problem i believe is the loop. it is function select.quote that is not working

Comment: That is understood. What I am trying to ask is, what is happening now. what error message you may be getting. What issue are you facing?
"not working" can mean a lot of things. What are you getting at the browser console?

Comment: I have this error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: select is not defined

Comment: what is select.quote? have you defined select anywhere? why don't you simply change a second function without select.quote and give it a name like the first one and call it from click handler and remove finalQuote() call from handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a lot that could be done to tidy up your code, but the below should work, there are lots of ways of solving this problem.

```
let array1 = [ "peace " , "love" , "money"];
let array2 = [ "will be " , "will never be ", "maybe will be"];
let array3 = ["your end", "your start", "your tasks"];

function checkStringForMatch (str, word) {
    return str.indexOf(word) !== -1
}

function finalQuote(...arrs) {
let quote = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) {
        quote += arrs[i][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + ' ';
    }
    if (checkStringForMatch(quote, 'peace') && checkStringForMatch(quote, 'will be') && checkStringForMatch(quote, 'your end')){
        alert("you found me!");
    } else {
        alert(quote)
    }
}

qt_btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    finalQuote(array1, array2, array3);
});
```